# Is it possible to add a package from a private GitHub repo to an app in Swift Playgrounds for iPad?

Tags: ios, swift, swift-playground, swift-package-manager

I'm creating an app in Swift Playgrounds for iPad and can easily add Swift Packages from public GitHub repositories this way. But how can I add a package from my *private* repo? I've seen answers relating to using SSH via XCode but I'm on an iPad so am assuming these wouldn't work in my case. Is there a safe way to achieve this? And if not, is there an easy way?

When I've tried adding the https url of my repo via the "Add Package" menu item, I get the following error message:

> git error unknown(34):GIT_EAUTH - remote authentication required but
> no callback set

Comment: @JoakimDanielson My private repo. I've edited my original question to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a [similar question](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/701369) on the Apple Developer Forum and according to one of the answers it would work if you used a PAT (Personal Access Token).

Since I already have one set up I decided to try it and it worked fine with one of my private repos.

So create a PAT if you don't have it, see [GitHub: Create personal Access Token](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token) and then include it in the url when adding the package to your app

```
https://<your-PAT-string>@github.com/<your-username>/<your-repo-name>.git
```

Comment: Cheers. Confirming that solution works with a Fine-grained token as well as a Classic Token but have opted for the safer fine-grained version.